# C# - What are the best practices when creating custom lists using arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list, oop, generics

I've got some school work to practice some concepts like generics, delegates, and interfaces. The whole project is to build a custom list class using an array of `T`.
the class should also implement `IEnumerable` and have a struct which is an `IEnumerator`. I'm only focusing on the Add method here.

```
class MyList<T> : IEnumerable
{
    private static readonly T[] arrayStarter = new T[1];
    private int capacity = 1;
    private int currentItems = 1;

    public T[] TList { get; set; }

    public MyList()
    {
        TList = arrayStarter;
        TList[0] = default(T);
    }

    public  T[] Add(T[] tArray, T item)
    {
        T[] temp = new T[++capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < tArray.Length; i++)
            temp[i] = tArray[i];
        temp[tArray.Length] = item;
        currentItems++;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

When I'm creating an instance of my list and I want to add an item using the method it looks like this:

```
MyList<int> m = new MyList<int>();
m.TList = m.Add(m.TList, 5);
m.TList = m.Add(m.TList, 7);
m.TList = m.Add(m.TList, 13);
m.TList = m.Add(m.TList, 15);
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to make a custom list I hope someone out there has a good insight on the matter.

Comment: You should double the size of the array if the new size exceeds the capacity. And you should not return the array, it's just an internal storage. Provide an indexer.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, or even possible, to assign to your list class's `TList` property.  That should be private, and inaccessible to the outside world.  You're getting into opinion territory though.  I believe this question would be better suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: You may also want to consider implementing `IList` and its generic variants,  in addition to `IEnumerable` so that it can be used more places.

Comment: Peculiar thing to have the list contain an initial default item ...

Comment: The first thing what comes in mind when I saw how do you add items: signature of `Add` method looks like an extension method, which are **not** a part of the class. That looks faulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation demonstrates that you are missing the point of encapsulation in general, and of using private members in particular. Since you made `TList` array a member of your list class, you have an ability to hide it from your users completely. Your users should be able to write

```
m.Add(5);
m.Add(7);
```

instead of

```
m.TList = m.Add(m.TList, 5);
m.TList = m.Add(m.TList, 7);
```

and not worry about `m.TList`'s presence at all.

Fortunately, you can do it very easily: make `TList` a private field, rename it to something that starts in lower case letter to follow [C#'s naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), remove it from the list of `Add`'s parameters, and change `Add` to not return anything. This would match [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)'s signature, which you should consider implementing.

Once you've made this work, consider "divorcing" `capacity` from `currentItems`, letting the first one grow faster, and the other one catching up to it as more items are added. This would reduce the number of re-allocations.

As a final point, consider switching to using [`Array.Resize<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid manual copying of data.

Comment: Since he's rebuilding a `List<T>` he could look at it's [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Absolutely! However, it's probably more instructive to try writing it from scratch first, and then "compare notes" with Microsoft engineers.

Comment: True, otherwise it's too easy to just copy&paste their code without learning anything

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm still brand new, just starting out with the more complicated concepts such as interfaces and etc... the amount of fluff I got from implementing IList<T> is overwhelming... as there any walkthrough for this?

Comment: @DaniRashba Not really - apart from the documentation, there is nothing there to walk you through every single method of `IList<T>`. For an initial attempt at this it's probably a good idea to pretend that you are implementing `IList<T>` without actually implementing the interface, i.e. pick the methods that you wish to implement, and stick to their signatures from the interface.

Comment: @DaniRashba what i've done in the past, add the interface to your class, and let Visual Studio generate the code for all of the members.  Then comment out all of the generated code, and remove the interface from your class.  You can now pick and choose which methods you wish to play around with.  Uncomment the `Add` method, and start plugging away at it without changing the method signature.  You can either remove the rest of the commented out code, or implement it at your leisure.  This can make it less intimidating by letting you work at your own pace rather than all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `List<>`'s `Add()` method implementation in [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9cc11588bffd57c1) or with ILSpy, you'll see this:

```
private int _size;
private T[] _items;

public void Add(T item)
{
    if (this._size == this._items.Length)
    {
        this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
    }
    this._items[this._size++] = item;
    this._version++;
}

private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
    if (this._items.Length < min)
    {
        int num = (this._items.Length != 0) ? (this._items.Length * 2) : 4;
        if (num > 2146435071)
        {
            num = 2146435071;
        }
        if (num < min)
        {
            num = min;
        }
        this.Capacity = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for a decompiler, it's open source meanwhile: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9cc11588bffd57c1

Comment: Yeap, thanks, I forgot about this resource. :) (I was decompiling some library at that moment, so decided to look inside)